# GetOpenFileName() custom filtering

Tags: winapi

I have a folder with a number of DLLs in it, some of them contain a specific routine (let's call it `connect()`), and some do not. Those which do contain that routine are considered as plugin DLLs. I want to use `GetOpenFileName()` to acquire a plugin DLL name to work with.

It is necessary not only to filter out all files that do not match the `*.dll` pattern, but also to check all of them for the presence of the `connect()` function.

Is it possible to achieve that with `GetOpenFileName()`? As I can see, it's possible to provide a hook procedure for it, however it is not clear whether this hook is suitable for file filtering.